# Docker container inaccessible from host

Tags: tomcat, docker

I am trying to get a tomcat application server running on a docker container. The server is working, but I cannot access it from the host machine.

The command that I am running to start the container is

```
docker run -d -p 9080:9080 example/server
```

On a shell within the container I can type

```
curl localhost:9080
```

to get a readout of what the server should yield. This works correctly. However, if I attempt this from the host machine I get the following error message:

```
curl: (56) Failure when receiving data from the peer
```

If I replicate the process with a normal Apache server, everything works as it should.

Comment: better to provide the `Dockerfile` for your `example/server` and your docker version and environment. Difficult to get answer without those information

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have solved this issue. The server was configured by default to use 'localhost' as the host which does not work properly with docker. I edited the configuration file to use host="*" and now everything works as it should.

Comment: Thanks so much for this answer! I was struggling all day with my Gunicorn server having the same problem. After reading your answer, I changed its default host from `127.0.0.1` (which is not accessible from outside the container) to `0.0.0.0` (which accepts any host) and it worked finally!